# jQuery - Javascript equivalent to PHP's htmlentities() function

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain to my why the code snippet belows act like PHP's htmlentities()?

`$('<div />').text(value).html();`

Also, does this work in new versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only seems to act like PHP's htmlentities() for characters which would have special meaning in HTML, such as < and >. When you call `$('<div/>').text('<br>')`, you create a div element and then fill it with the text, `<br>`. The angle brackets are converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` in the HTML so that they aren't interpreted as HTML tags. The div element then looks like this:

```
<div>&lt;br&gt;</div>
```

If .text() didn't escape the brackets, you would get this instead:

```
<div><br></div>
```

...and that wouldn't contain the text, `<br>`, it would contain a br element instead.

Calling .html() on that element then gets you the HTML code inside the element, which has the angle brackets converted to HTML entities. There are plenty of characters that this won't escape though. For example, © won't get converted to `&copy;`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess it is good enough then since I only want to escape html tags.